# Pop-Up window only displays when form is hidden

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sockets, console-application

Basically, the program I'm working on is a C# console application that listens to requests via sockets. Once a connection is made, it calls and shows a Windows form named **frmPdfViewer**.

In **frmPdfViewer**, there is a ToolStripMenuItem named **Sign**. When it is clicked, it should show a signature pop-up window for the user to sign.

Now my problem is when I click the **Sign**ToolStripMenuItem, the form freezes and doesn't show the signature pop-up window. No errors or exceptions were thrown, it just freezes. But when I try hiding the **frmPdfViewer** after clicking **Sign**, the signature pop-up window appears.

Why does it have such behavior?

Here is the snippet for the socket code (Inside **ProcReq()** method is where the form will be called):

```
        var wsURI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsURI"];
        var id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["id"];
        var ns = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["namespace"];
        var type = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["type"];

        var socket = IO.Socket(wsURI + "/" + ns);

        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
        {
            // Construct Push Message for Device Registration
            JObject reg = MessageFactory.CreateRegistrationMessage(id,
            "RR_" + id, type);

            socket.Emit("peripheral/registration", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reg));

            socket.On(ns + "/RR_" + id, (reqMsg) =>
            {
                JObject req = reqMsg as JObject;
                JObject reqHeader = (JObject)req["header"];

                RespPayload respPayload = TabletTerminal.GetInstance().ProcReq(req);

                JObject resp = new JObject();
                resp.Add("header", reqHeader);
                resp.Add("payload", JObject.FromObject(respPayload));

                var jsonResp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp);

                socket.Emit(ns + "/RR_" + id, jsonResp);
            });
        })
```

Here is the snippet for the ProcReq method (This is where the form will be called):

```
public SignatureRespPayload ProcReq(JObject req)
        {
            SignatureRespPayload signatureRespPayload = new SignatureRespPayload();

            JObject reqPayload = req.GetValue("payload") as JObject;
            string name = (string)reqPayload["name"];
            string reason = (string)reqPayload["reason"];
            string pdfPath = (string)reqPayload["pdfPath"];

            frmPdfViewer pdfViewer = new frmPdfViewer(name, reason, pdfPath);
            pdfViewer.ShowDialog();
            signatureRespPayload.returnValue = pdfViewer.returnValue;

            if (signatureRespPayload.returnValue)
            {
                signatureRespPayload.signedPdfPath = pdfViewer.signedPdfPath;
            }
            else
            {
                signatureRespPayload.errorMessage = pdfViewer.errorMessage;
            }

            pdfViewer.Dispose();
            return signatureRespPayload;
        }
```

Here is the code snippet for the sign click event in frmPdfViewer:

(**Note:** I'm using a 3rd party SDK called Wacom Signature SDK and can only view the interface of their methods not the implementation. The method that shows the signature pop-up is **Capture()**)

```
try
        {
            SigCtl sigCtl = new SigCtl();
            sigCtl.Licence = Properties.Settings.Default.License;
            DynamicCapture dc = new DynamicCaptureClass();
            DynamicCaptureResult res = dc.Capture(sigCtl, name, reason, null, null);

            if (res == DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptOK)
            {
                SigObj sigObj = (SigObj)sigCtl.Signature;
                String filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
                sigObj.RenderBitmap(filename, 400, 200, "image/png", 0.5f, 0xff0000, 0xffffff, 10.0f, 10.0f, RBFlags.RenderOutputFilename | RBFlags.RenderColor32BPP | RBFlags.RenderEncodeData | RBFlags.RenderBackgroundTransparent);
                string newFile = InsertSignatureImageToPdf(filename);
                loadPdf(newFile, false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

**Note:** The signature pop-up window also appears when I place a breakpoint before the Capture() method and then continue to run the program.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the method and, after it breaks, use Debug > Windows > Threads.  Crystal ball says that you see that code running on a worker thread and not the Main thread.  Lots and lots of problems with that, the Z-order issue and the frozen look are but the small part of that.  Use BeginInvoke to ensure you create the form on the UI thread.

Comment: you could pass the current form as owner in the `ShowDialog()`

Comment: @HansPassant I see. I created a new method called CaptureSignature() and moved the sign click event code there. After that I placed `Invoke(new MethodInvoker(CaptureSignature));` in the sign click event but it still didn't work. I haven't really used Invoke() before so can you tell me how to properly use it in this case?

Comment: You need to use the BeginInvoke() method of a form that definitely was created on the main thread.  Typically your main window.   If you are desperate to get the proper object reference then Application.OpenForms[0].BeginInvoke(...) tends to help.

Comment: @HansPassant My main window is the console application. So are you saying that I should use that code after showing the form (ie pdfViewer.ShowDialog();)?

Comment: @HansPassant This is the flow of my program: Console app > PdfViewer form > Signature form. Based on your previous comment, I'm a bit confused on what to put as argument in Invoke() since my problem is the **Signature form** won't open and it will only be called from the PdfViewer form when I click the Sign button.

Answer (score 1):

You could try add `formvariable.BringToFront()` after you show the form.